# How to hide embebed player when no video is present?

Tags: php, html

I made this code, and it works, my problem is how to hide the embedded if no video is present. because it shows an empty(white) image, and its ugly.

```
<?
require_once("include/imdb.class.php");
$oIMDB = new IMDB('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt'.$detail['imdb'].'/');
$trailer = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$detail['ytube'].'&hl=de_DE&fs=1&color1=0x3a3a3a&color2=0x999999';
if($oIMDB->isReady){
    $cover = '<img src="include/'.$oIMDB->getPoster().'" id="imdb_cover" alt="" />';
} else {
    echo '<p></p>';
}
?>
<?=$cover;?><embed width="420" height="345" src="<?=$trailer;?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> </embed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what determines if no video is present? If something in php indicates it you could use a simple conditional like:

```
if ($detail['ytube']) {
  // render your video
}
```

Comment: My new code:                                                     <?if ($detail['ytube']) {?>
<embed
width="420" height="345"
src="<?=$trailer;?>"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>
<?}else {echo '<p></p>';}?>